# Related rates and velocity

Tags: calculus

A pedestrian $2~\text{m}$ tall walks directly away from a street light $6~\text{m}$ above the ground at $80~\text{m}/\text{min}$. When he is $8~\text{m}$ away from the post, determine the velocity of the end of his shadow.

Comment: Draw a diagram of everything that you are told. Hint: Finding the angle between the street light and the top of the pedestrian's head will be useful.

Comment: @Mayor : I don't think finding the angle will be useful in this case.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I would have thought that finding the perpendicular distance from the street light to the tip of the shadow would been useful?

Comment: @Maylor : See my answer below.  If I wanted the distance from the light itself (rather than the point on the ground under it) to the end of his shadow, I would find it via the Pythagorean theorem without using the angle.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose he's $x$ meters away from the starting point.  Draw the right triangle from the light straight down (vertically) to the initial position of the top of his head, then horizontally from there to the present position of the top of his head, then from there straight back to the light.  Draw the larger right triangle from the light vertically straight down to the ground, then from there to the end of his shadow, then from there straight back to the light.  Those two triangles have the same shape; hence the same ratios of lengths of sides.

$6$ is to $8$ as $x$ is to $\dfrac 8 6 x$.  Hence the length of his shadow is $\dfrac 8 6 x$.  If $x$ grows at $80$ meters per minute, how fast does $\dfrac 8 6 x$ grow?